# How to remove system ui panel without root? On API 15 and higher

Tags: android

I need to remove (hide) system panel with buttons home, back and so on. I know only one way - execute comand

```
killall com.android.systemui
```

But for this i need root access and busybox. Is there any other way without need of root? Or is there any way to get root directly on android device, without connecting it to PC and running rooting programs?

Comment: Do you want to remove everything (NavBar and StatusBar) or just one of those?

Comment: Yes, i need to remove everything

Comment: That's not possible prior to API 19.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do the following. I have never done it myself though

```
  myView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
```